# Manage file name in a report

Tags: qgis, reports

QGIS3.22.4
In a shapefile (points), I have a report PDF exported for which I want to give a name consisting of a fix string (let say 'ReportNode') concatenated with the content of an attribute text field.

This text field generally unique, but with one or two exceptions.
Because of those exceptions, I would like to add a suffix to avoid the override when saving.

I found a quick solution, by just adding the id$, but what I would like to have is justadding a differentiator ONLY for those reports that have the same name.

IN the file name, I tested something with aggregate based on couting the number of items containing the same field. If more then one, add the id$ else adding ''.The problem is that I do not know how to write this aggregate, `aggregate ( Mylayer, aggregate:= count, expression:= Myfield, filter:= Myfield = "parent.myfield")`

and putting this in a if statement like : `"ReportNode" || Mylayer || (If aggregate....> 1 , to_string(id$), '')`, the filter is my problem, I don't know how to say that the `current Myfield` equals the `parent.myfield`, as the current layer and the parent layer are the same layer.

Answer (score 1):

IN the meantime, I found a solution for the filter:
filter:= "MyField" = attribute(@parent, 'MyField').